How do I inquire into windows server about resources from a client java app
I'm building a balancer app using Java.
This app will provide REST services to tell requesters which would be the best Windows server to use among some to do a certain job, . Those server will be inquired about current resource usage or availability and the evaluation on them should determine the outcome to send back as the answer.
I'm told the most current way to inquire a Windows server is calling their OMI (Open Management Infrastructure) api.
Can you suggest how to do it from Java?
Are there some library to simplify the code?
Currently I'm issuing calls to PowerShell cmdlet (mostly "query ") through a shell interface, collecting textual result back into my app, but I find it suboptimal.
Thank you,
Mirco
